# Download a file from a windows share using Ansible

Tags: download, ansible

I have a file in windows share. I need to download this file using ansible.
Playbook

```
- name: Copy installer 
  get_url:
     url: file:'\\Winserver\Share_Binary\Installer-v6.tar.gz'
     dest: /tmp
```

Error Output:

```
    "mode": "01777",
    "msg": "Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \"'\\\\\\\\Winserver\\\\Share_Binary\\\\Installer-v6.tar.gz'\">",
    "owner": "root",
    "size": 4096,
    "state": "directory",
    "uid": 0,
    "url": "file:'\\\\Winserver\\Share_Binary\\Installer-v6.tar.gz'"
```

The file exists.  When I paste `\\Winserver\Share_Binary\Installer-v6.tar.gz` in the file explorer in my system I could see the file. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a credential file and 3 Ansible tasks.

First, create a credential file (e.g. `/home/youruser/smbshare.cred`) containing the username and password of a service account with permissions to mount the CIFS share:

```
username=your_service_account_name
password=your_service_account_password
```

Make sure your remote ansible user owns the file (or root if you're using become) and it has 0400 permissions. You might consider generating this credential file with Ansible and/or encrypting it with Ansible Vault in the future as well.

Task 1: Use the [mount module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mount_module.html) to mount the SMB share on the target.

```
- name: Mount SMB share
  mount:
    path: /mnt/smbshare
    src: '\\\\Winserver\\Share_Binary'
    fstype: cifs
    opts: 'credentials=/home/youruser/smbshare.cred'
    state: mounted
```

Task 2: Use the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) to copy the file wherever you actually want it.

```
- name: Copy installer tarball to target
  copy:
    src: /mnt/smbshare/Installer-v6.tar.gz
    dest: /some/local/path/Installer-v6.tar.gz
    owner: foo
    group: foo
    mode: 0640
```

Task 3: Use the mount module to unmount the SMB share.

```
- name: Unmount SMB share
  mount:
    path: /mnt/smbshare
    state: unmounted
```

Note: Depending on your environment, you might need to add more mount options (refer to mount.cifs(8) man page) to the `opts:` parameter in task 1.

Comment: I get error as  "msg": "Error mounting /mnt/smbshare: mount error(112): Host is down\nRefer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)\n". Host is not down, am able to access manually via file explorer

Answer (score 0):

not sure if `get_url` is capable to do that. Pls try this one:

```
  - name: Get file from smb.
    command:
      smbclient //Winserver/Share_Binary/ <pass> -U <user> -c "get Installer-v6.tar.gz"
      creates=/tmp/Installer-v6.tar.gz
```

Of course, you have to install `smbclient` first

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not supposed to install smbclient. Looking for some other workaround